# PHP object class not getting the submit field value

Tags: php

When I print the `$letter` variable, I am not getting the correct value.  It always coming `0`.

*index.php*

```
<form method="get" class="txtweb-form" action="index.php">
   Guess a letter: <input type="text" name="txtweb-message" />
   <input type="submit" value="submit" name="guess" />
</form>

<?php
$params = (object) $_REQUEST;
//print_r($params);
if (isset($params->guess)) {
  $letter = $params->txtweb-message;
  echo $letter;exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: Why are you casting `$_REQUEST` to object?  Why are you using `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_GET`?

Comment: `txtweb-message` is not a valid variable/property name.

Comment: `var_dump($_REQUEST)` to see what you've actually got. And I would recommend just using `$_GET` instead of `$_REQUEST` since your form is `method='get'`.

Comment: *Don't* do `(object) $_REQUEST`!  Just do `$letter = $_REQUEST['txtweb-message']`, or better yet `$letter = $_GET['txtweb-message']`.

Comment: Using the object, you would need to wrap it in `{}` as `$params->{'txtweb-message'}` which is a strong indicator that you shouldn't bother casting an object.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Thanks for commenting here. i am using your code it is working now.

Answer (score 2):

You need to probably use `_` instead of `-` in input name. `-` is not a valid character in PHP variable of property names.

What is actually happening is this:

```
$letter = $params->txtweb - message; // a subtraction operation
```

You end up subtracting an unset constant `message` from an unset object property `$params->txtweb`. Thus you get `0`.

You can keep `-` in input name but you should use `$_REQUEST['txtweb-message']` or `$_GET['txtweb-message']` (without casting to object) to retrieve the value.

There really is no reason whatsoever to cast the superglobal array to an object, and this is what introduced your issue.

An additional note here.  You really should be developing with error reporting turned on.  That operation shown above would have resulted in two warnings showing up, which could have helped you understand what is happening.

Comment: No `txtweb-message` is the text field name. just `print_r($params);` you will know that parameter is coming in object class.

Comment: @chatfun I know, but since `-` is not a valid character in PHP variable or property label, the subtraction is what IS actually happening.  You are subtracting and unset constant `message` from an unset object property `$params->txtweb`. Thus the result is 0.

Comment: Yes you are right. when i change my field name `txtweb-message` to `txtwebmessage` then print `$letter = $params->txtwebmessage;` i am getting correct.

Comment: I got my answer @MichaelBerkowski posted comment here please check `$params->{'txtweb-message'}`

Comment: @chatfun You should accept Mike's answer, for explaining what went wrong and why you got the strange result.

Comment: @chatfun Yes. That will work as well. I don't intend to update my answer, as my belief is that is a bad workaround for the ill-conceived idea to cast the array to object in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

why are you casting into an object?
wouldn't treating it as an array be easier like

```
<?php
$params = $_REQUEST;
if (isset($params["guess"])) {
  $letter = $params["txtweb-message"];
  echo $letter;exit;
}
?>
```